# Updating a node module without updating its dependencies

Tags: node.js, git, npm, node-modules

We have our own node module that we use to keep shared code for several of our internal projects.  The entry in package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "git+https://github.secureserver.net/MyProject/foo.git#master",
}
```

As a matter of practice, we keep our dependent node modules checked into git along with the project code.  For example, our tree in git looks something like this:

```
application\
config\
package.json
node_modules\
test\
```

Whenever we do an "npm update foo" in any of the projects that depends on foo we get the updated foo but then npm also updates the node modules that foo depends on even though they are checked into git along with foo.  This is not what we want.  On "npm update" we want foo and all of its node modules to exactly mirror what's in master because that's what foo was tested with.  We could require exact versions of modules in the package.json in foo but that makes updating foo's dependencies more problematic when we want to check in new versions.  How can we get "npm update foo" to pull foo from Github without having it update foo's node_modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html)!

In the `foo` project directory, run `npm shrinkwrap`.  This will generate a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` with the installed versions of your dependencies, their dependencies, all the way down.

When `npm install` is run against `foo`, the versions specified in `npm-shrinkwrap.json` will take precedence over `package.json`.

One caveat: `npm` won't look in `package.json` at all, so if you use `npm install --save` or edit `package.json` directly to install new packages, you'll need to also rerun `npm shrinkwrap`.